# Specifying button clicked in multiple forms in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I need help with some Javascript.

Inside my html I have a form that repeated twice.

```
<form method='post' action='php page'>
   <input type=text id=something name=something value='' />
   <input type="submit" id="final_submit" value="yes">
</form>
```

This exact form is repeated twice. In javascript when someone clicks on the submit button I need to be able to determine which button was clicked to get the value of something in that form. Right now its automatically just getting the value for the first form even though I click the button on the second form.

Any ideas please.

Comment: if this "exact" same form is repeated twice then you have two fields with the same ID.  This would be invalid and something you would want to fix.

Comment: Ok so what would i need to do?

Comment: give the fields a different `id` attribute but the same name. Form one, `something` field would be `something1`, form 2's -- `something2`, etc. The server would get the same request, but then you can reference the two forms

Comment: It may help you to look here: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php - If you set a name for each submit with different values (ie Form1 and Form2) then you have  a name value pair returned that tells you which form was submitted...and like above you shouldn't have 2 elements with the same id. +1 to @bokonic for beating me to it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in the comments, using duplicate id is wrong. Here is a way to get the value of the input that will work also in using older browsers [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLFormElement) and [`forms.element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.elements)

```
var forms = document.forms;
for(var i=0, l= forms.length; i++){
  forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = e.target;
   var value = form.elements[0].value;
  })
}
```

This will add a submit event listener to every form in your side and that stops the event and get the value from the first input field in this form.

Comment: Note that addEventListener will not work in older browsers (I guess you mean Internet Explorer 7 and below, since they do not support querySelectorAll), since I believe any (more than 1% market share) browser that supports addEventListener, also supports querySelectorAll.

Comment: Sure you have to add the use the right method to add the event listener in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
function determineForm(e)
{

 // This prevents the form from actually being submitted.
 // Just remove it when you are done debugging.
 e.preventDefault();

 if (document.querySelectorAll("form")[0] === e.target)
 {
  alert("Form1");
 }
 else
 {
  alert("Form2");
 }
}
document.addEventListener("submit", determineForm, false);
```

Comment: Note that this will not work in IE8 and older, in cause of `document. addEventListener` and the point that the `submit` event dont bubble

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 does support document.querySelectorAll, it does not support addEventListener, though.